# Почему вылетает исключение?

Tags: java, html, jsp, исключения

Использую GlassFish. Только начал изучать jsp.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<%request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");%>
<%= "Привет"%><h3><%=request.getParameter("username")%>
</h3>

<h3>
    ${param("username")}
</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Видимо проблема в строке  `${param("username")}`

Почему вылетает вот такое исключение?

```
StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception 
javax.el.ELException: Expression uses functions, but no FunctionMapper was provided 
at com.sun.el.parser.AstFunction.getValue(AstFunction.java:187) 
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) 
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.evaluateExpression(PageContextImpl.java:1016) 
at org.apache.jsp.pages.main_jsp._jspService(main_jsp.java:60) 
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473) 
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673) 
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как после `param` идут круглые скобки, компилятор решает, что это метод, но не понимает метод чего. Если вы хотите получить параметр запроса с именем "username", то используйте квадратные скобки: `${param["username"]}`.